# Modifying the data in PHP

Tags: php, replace, preg-match-all

How can I modify this data:

```
(13, 'µµ+3                    ', 'Miecz +3', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 14, 4, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(14, 'µµ+4                    ', 'Miecz +4', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 15, 5, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 28, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 30, 1, 0),
(15, 'µµ+5                    ', 'Miecz +5', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 16, 6, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 35, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 40, 1, 0),
(16, 'µµ+6                    ', 'Miecz +6', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 17, 7, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 42, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 50, 1, 0),
(17, 'µµ+7                    ', 'Miecz +7', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 18, 8, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 49, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 65, 1, 0),
(18, 'µµ+8                    ', 'Miecz +8', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 19, 9, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 56, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 80, 1, 0),
(19, 'µµ+9                    ', 'Miecz +9', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 63, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 100, 1, 0),
(20, 'Ŕĺ°Ë+0                  ', 'Dlugi Miecz +0', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 400, 0, 21, 1, 0, 15, 1, 5, 0, 0, 7, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 15, 15, 19, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(21, 'Ŕĺ°Ë+1                  ', 'Dlugi Miecz +1', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 400, 0, 22, 2, 0, 15, 1, 5, 0, 0, 7, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 15, 15, 19, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
(22, 'Ŕĺ°Ë+2                  ', 'Dlugi Miecz +2', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 400, 0, 23, 3, 0, 15, 1, 5, 0, 0, 7, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 15, 15, 19, 14, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
```

Into a query, like this:

```
UPDATE `itemproto`
SET `name` = 'µµ+3'
WHERE `id` = 13;

UPDATE `itemproto`
SET `name` = 'µµ+4'
WHERE `id` = 14;
```

...

```
UPDATE `itemproto`
SET `name` = 'Ŕĺ°Ë+2'
WHERE `id` = 22;
```

..etc. There are hundreds of data, I've just gave you a little cut, because file weight is a some nice MB. But ok, let me explain, what do I want to reach:

Fe. there is a line like this...

```
(13, 'µµ+3                    ', 'Miecz +3', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 14, 4, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
```

Then the script should rewrite the above line into a query:

```
UPDATE `itemproto`
SET `name` = 'µµ+3'
WHERE `id` = 13;
```

You just need the following info from each line to build a query:

`(13, 'µµ+3                    ' ,` etc....

I think it can be done using `preg_replace` or `preg_match`, but I have no idea about the regex.

Anyway, I will try to explain one more time in case if you still don't get it:

I got hundreds of lines like this (with random names, numbers) :

```
(13, 'µµ+3                    ', 'Miecz +3', 1, 0, 0, 2, 32, 1, 16, '', 100, 0, 14, 4, 0, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 19, 13, 15, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0),
```

Now the script should grep this info: `(13, 'µµ+3`, and based on these info, should build the following query:

```
UPDATE `itemproto`
SET `name` = 'µµ+3'
WHERE `id` = 13;
```

And thats all.

I know its a little bit complicated, but as you know, everything can be done using PHP. So thats why I'm using it, but um, in case if you still don't understand the question, **feel free to post a comment**, and I'll reply!

Comment: You have id=13, and name='µµ+3                    '. What is it you actually want to CHANGE in the query. You haven't even explained that. It seems like what you are trying to do is get rid of the spaces around 'µµ+3                    '. If that's the case, there is a VERY EASY way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat simplistic solution:

```
$data = file("path/to/file.txt"); // returns an array of the lines
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $temp = explode(',', $val);
    $id = trim(substr($temp[0], 1));
    $name = trim($temp[1]);
    $query = "UPDATE `itemproto`
        SET `name` = '$name'
        WHERE `id` = $id;";
    // Do work here
}
```

Comment: Looking at the other solutions, the only part of this code worth keeping is the `file()` command to read the file into an array.

Comment: I see from Cyclone's other comment that his data is in a file. Cyclone, you might want to try mentioning that kind of information in your next question.

Comment: Ah, that works then. I was going to suggest, that using `explode()` might be too much (looking at the size of the data. Using regex would be more effective in this case.

Comment: @ButtleButkus The question says: `file weight is a some nice MB`

Comment: "file weight is some nice MB", lol. Somehow I assumed that was still in reference to a DB table since it was mentioned only in passing around line 50. From what I've seen, don't use regex if you can use one of the more basic functions. Regex is extremely slow. Your answer is good if it is a one-time job, but if he has to deal with this problem repeatedly, I think it might be faster to just LOAD DATA INFILE, get all the data into the database, then use an UPDATE query between the two tables.

Comment: @Grexis

I don't really care about the effectivity because I just need to rewrite my data, and then maybe add this script to the archive `:p`. Btw. `explode( )` ain't that bad in my case, because I've done with my 3437902 lines within' a 1 minute or something, lol.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Charlie Somerville's answer, but only prepares the PDOStatement object once.  It will as a result be significantly faster.

```
$prepped = $pdo -> prepare ("UPDATE some_table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?");
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // I'm guessing the first element of each row is the id, and the second is the name
    list ($id, $name) = $row;
    // There should be some error checking here, but for the sake of simplicity I've left it out.
    $prepped -> execute (array ($id, $name));
}
```